# How to schedule a job that depends on network availability?

Tags: networking, cron

I have cloned a Git repository of some project. I want to automate `git pull` and compile the project once in a week. I am using a laptop which won't be on 24x7. 
Now, I cannot use `cron` as I should keep the system running at that exact moment. I cannot use `anacron` either, as it might start before I connect to network.
Is there some option in `anacron` that will run this particular job only when I am connected to internet? Or should I be using some other different tool for this?

Comment: Your network configuration manager may be able to execute code after the network is brought up.

Comment: Yes. but I dont want the job to be run everytime the network is up. I want to run only once in a week.

Comment: The script could touch a file and check mtime on that file each time it runs.

Comment: hmm.. yes. I can write a wrapper on my own but I think there must be some tool which handles it better.

Comment: Is waiting inside the script for network availability out of the question?

Comment: I think there is no such tool as your task is quite specific. The term 'network is available' is quite wide. The interface ma be up, but the repository is unreachable. So, IMO the proper solution will be to write a script (or extend your script if it exist) that will first ping with -c and -w options the host with repository and then decides if it is good idea to start `git pull`, then touch a file as jordanm proposed (the check on that file to be performed at the beginning of the script)

Comment: The question might be phrased specific, but the idea was to run anacron only when a particular condition is fulfilled (here: network connection) and that is widely useful. It would also be nice to have a conditional retry, e.g. “run this job once per day successfully, if it returns non-zero, retry once per hour”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the job when you connect to the network. Most distributions have a scripting infrastructure that you can plug into, though you will need root permissions. If you connect with NetworkManager or Wicd, they have their own hook infrastructure as well. Add a cron job that only runs if the network is available (and, optionally, only if the job hasn't been run performed in a long time), in case the network remains connected for a long time.

You don't specify your distribution, so I'll give an example for a Debian-based distribution. The scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d` are executed after an interface is brought up; see the [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5) man page for more information. Write a script `/etc/network/if-up.d/zzzz_balki_git_pull` such as this:

```
#!/bin/sh
su balki -c /home/balki/bin/pull_repository_if_old
```

with a `pull_repository_if_old` that does something like this (run `git pull` if the network is available unless there is a timestamp that is less than 7 days old):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if [ -z "$(find /path/to/.repository.pull.timestamp -mtime -7)" ] &&
   ping -c 1 -w 1 repository.example.com >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
then
  cd /path/to/repository
  git pull
  touch /path/to/.repository.pull.timestamp
fi
EOF
```

And a crontab entry on your account:

```
28 4 * * * /home/balki/bin/pull_repository_if_old
```

Comment: Thanks. But for such a simple task, I need to 1. Write a script 2. Have root permissions 3. Do distribution specific hooking 4. Write a cron tab entry 5. Create a timestamp file. :( I wish the experience was better.

Answer (score 4):

Use `anacron`, because you won't be up 24/7, then add some magic to ensure the network is up (by pinging the default gateway), and if not delay the execution.

Here's an example script that will get you close:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd repo
JOB="git pull"
ping -c 2 $(netstat -rn | awk '/^0.0.0.0/ {print $2}') 2>&1 > /dev/null && $JOB || echo $JOB | at $(date --date="+1 hour" +%H:%M)
```